# Shorten Lua code irrigation timer

Tags: lua

Hi I am new to coding and set about doing some code for a irrigation controller running on the Control By Web Product which uses Lua.

My spec was for it to Operate as follows

- - Set a register for each valve run time. Then trigger the sequence so they water one after another.
  - Ability to pause the sequence (timers) and have the valve turn off
    while paused and restart the timers and turn valve on when unpaused.
  - Ability to manually start valves and any time
  - Have a number of sequences happening at the same time in the same
    script.

I have done the below script but it is to big more that 8KB allowed. I'm sure there is ways to make it smaller but is beyond me at this stage.

If anyone is willing to have a go. I am willing to pay to have this code fixed up. 
Cheers 
Jon

---

```
-- Sequence Timer for the control of 4 valves and fertigation on Control By Web X600


-- Flag Variabls for each Valve relay
flagV1 = 0  --Valve 1
flagV2 = 0
flagV3 = 0
f = 0

-- Flag Variables for Valve sequence

g = 0   -- sequence active 
h = 0   -- valve 1 Finished
i = 0   -- valve 2 Finished
j = 0   -- valve 3 Finished
k = 0   -- valve 5 Finished


-- Flag Veriables for fert relays
f_Agitate = 0
f_Inject = 0

-- flag Virables for fert seqance
   flagFertRunning = 0
    flagAgitateFin = 0
     flagInjectFin = 0
while true do

    print ("flagV1 V1 ",flagV1)
    print ("flagV2 V2 ",flagV2)
    print ("flagV3 V3 ",flagV3)
    print ("g triggrer ",g)

  if reg.rArea1active == 1 and
    reg.rTriggerArea1 == 1 then
      g = 1
     else if reg.rArea1active == 0 then   -- reset the seqence
      g = 1
      h = 1
      i = 1
      j = 1
      k = 1
     end
   end

  -- start valve 1
  if g == 1 and reg.rRunTimeV1 > 0 and 
     h == 0 then -- only start if this valve hasn't already run
     io.valve1 = 1
     else if reg.rRunTimeV1 <= 0 then
     h = 1
     end
  end

-- ******control for valve 1

    -- Moves the run time into the timer if relay tuned on and timer O
            if io.valve1 == 1 and
                reg.rTimeToOffV1 == 0 and
                               flagV1 == 0 then
                               flagV1 = 1   -- Valve has been opened 
                  reg.rTimeToOffV1 = reg.rRunTimeV1
                print ("V1 if-1 ",io.valve1)
            end

    -- count down if relay on
            if reg.rTimeToOffV1 > 0 and
                io.valve1 == 1 then
                         flagV1 = 1 -- Valve has been opened 
                if reg.t3second == 0 then
                     reg.rTimeToOffV1 = reg.rTimeToOffV1-.5
              print ("V1 time to off " ,reg.rTimeToOffV1) 
              end

  -- Start fert
                  if reg.rFertV1 == 1 and
                   reg.rTimeToOffV1 <= reg.rFertStartTime then
                     reg.rRunFert = 1
                  end

            end

    -- turns relay off if timer 0
         if  reg.rTimeToOffV1 <= 0 and
                                flagV1 == 1 then
                       io.valve1 = 0
                     reg.rRunFert = 0
                reg.rTimeToOffV1 = 0
                    if io.valve1 == 0 then flagV1 = 0 -- timer finished valve closed                
                    end                
                    if g == 1 then h = 1   --valve 1 finished lock                
                    print ("V1 if-3 ",io.valve1)
                   end
          end

  -- start valve 2
   if g == 1 and reg.rRunTimeInject > 0 and 
      h == 1 and
      i == 0 then -- only start if this valve hasn't already run
      io.valve2 = 1
      else if reg.rRunTimeInject <= 0 then
      i = 1
      end
   end



-- *****control for Valve 2

    -- Moves the run time into the timer if relay tuned on and timer O
      if io.valve2 == 1 and
         reg.rTimeToOffV2 == 0 and
                            flagV2 == 0 then
                              flagV2 = 1    -- Valve has been opened 
                  reg.rTimeToOffV2 = reg.rRunTimeInject
                    print ("V2 if-1 ",io.valve2)
          end

     -- count down if relay on
             if  reg.rTimeToOffV2 > 0 and
                     io.valve2 == 1 and
                       reg.t3second == 0 then
                                   flagV2 = 1   -- Valve has been opened 
                   reg.rTimeToOffV2 = reg.rTimeToOffV2-.5

         print ("V2 time to off " ,reg.rTimeToOffV2)
     end

    -- turns relay off if timer 0
         if  reg.rTimeToOffV2 <= 0 and
                                flagV2 == 1 then
                               io.valve2 = 0
                           reg.rTimeToOffV2 = 0
                                  if io.valve2 == 0 then flagV2 = 0 -- timer finished valve closed
                                  end
                                  if g == 1 then i = 1  -- valve 2 finished lock
                                  end
                    print ("V2 if-3 ",io.valve2)
         end


-- start valve 3
   if g == 1 and reg.rRunTimeV3 > 0 and
      h == 1 and
      i == 1 and
      j == 0 then -- only start if this valve hasn't already run
    io.valve3 = 1
     else if reg.rRunTimeV3 <= 0 then
     h = 1
     end
    end

-- ******control for Valve 3

    -- Moves the run time into the timer if relay tuned on and timer O
      if io.valve3 == 1 and
         reg.rTimeToOffV3 == 0 and
                            flagV3 == 0 then
                            flagV3 = 1  -- Valve has been opened 
                  reg.rTimeToOffV3 = reg.rRunTimeV3
    print ("V3 if-1 ",io.valve3)
          end

     -- count down if relay on
             if  reg.rTimeToOffV3 > 0 and
                     io.valve3 == 1 and
                       reg.t3second == 0 then
                                   flagV3 = 1   -- Valve has been opened 
                   reg.rTimeToOffV3 = reg.rTimeToOffV3-.5
         print ("V3 time to off " ,reg.rTimeToOffV3)
     end

    -- turns relay off if timer 0
         if  reg.rTimeToOffV3 <= 0 and
                                flagV3 == 1 then
                               io.valve3 = 0
                           reg.rTimeToOffV3 = 0
                                  if io.valve3 == 0 then flagV3 = 0 -- timer finished valve closed
                                  end
                                  if g == 1 then j = 1  -- valve 3 finished lock
                                  end
                 print ("V3 if-3 ",io.valve3)
         end

  -- reset the seqence
   if g == 1 and
      h == 1 and 
      i == 1 and
      j == 1 then
            g = 0
            h = 0
            i = 0
            j = 0
            k = 0
   end

   -- ******************Fert control ********************************************


    if reg.rFertActive == 1 and
             rRunFert  == 1 then
              flagFertRunning = 1
     else if reg.rFertActive == 0 then   -- reset the seqence
             flagFertRunning = 1
              flagAgitateFin = 1
               flagInjectFin = 1
     end
   end

  -- Start Agitate
  if flagFertRunning == 1 and reg.rRunTimeAgitate > 0 and 
     flagAgitateFin == 0 then -- only start if this valve hasn't already run
     reg.fertAgitate = 1
     else if reg.rRunTimeAgitate <= 0 then
     flagAgitateFin = 1
     end
  end

-- ******control for Agitate

    -- Moves the run time into the timer if relay tuned on and timer O
            if reg.fertAgitate == 1 and
                reg.rTimeToOffAgitate == 0 and
                               f_Agitate == 0 then
                               f_Agitate = 1    -- Valve has been opened 
                  reg.rTimeToOffAgitate = reg.rRunTimeAgitate
                print ("V1 if-1 ",reg.fertAgitate)
            end

    -- count down if relay on
            if reg.rTimeToOffAgitate > 0 and
                reg.fertAgitate == 1 then
                         f_Agitate = 1  -- Valve has been opened 
                if reg.t3second == 0 then
                     reg.rTimeToOffAgitate = reg.rTimeToOffAgitate-.5
                end
              print ("V1 time to off " ,reg.rTimeToOffAgitate) 
              end



    -- turns relay off if timer 0
         if  reg.rTimeToOffAgitate <= 0 and
                                f_Agitate == 1 then
                       reg.fertAgitate = 0
                     reg.rRunFert = 0
                reg.rTimeToOffAgitate = 0
                    if reg.fertAgitate == 0 then f_Agitate = 0 -- timer finished valve closed               
                    end                
                    if flagFertRunning == 1 then flagAgitateFin = 1   --valve 1 finished lock                
                    print ("V1 if-3 ",reg.fertAgitate)
                   end
          end

  -- ***************start Inject**********************
   if flagFertRunning == 1 and reg.rRunTimeInject > 0 and 
      flagAgitateFin == 1 and
      flagInjectFin == 0 then -- only start if this valve hasn't already run
      io.fertPump = 1
      else if reg.rRunTimeInject <= 0 then
      flagInjectFin = 1
      end
   end


-- *****control for inject *****************

    -- Moves the run time into the timer if relay tuned on and timer O
      if io.fertPump == 1 and
         reg.rTimeToOffInject == 0 and
                            f_Inject == 0 then
                            f_Inject = 1    -- Valve has been opened 
                  reg.rTimeToOffInject = reg.rRunTimeInject
                    print ("V2 if-1 ",io.fertPump)
          end

     -- count down if relay on
             if  reg.rTimeToOffInject > 0 and
                     io.fertPump == 1 and
                    reg.t3second == 0 then
                                   f_Inject = 1 -- Valve has been opened 
                       reg.rTimeToOffInject = reg.rTimeToOffInject-.5

         print ("V2 time to off " ,reg.rTimeToOffInject)
     end

    -- turns relay off if timer 0
         if  reg.rTimeToOffInject <= 0 and
                         f_Inject == 1 then
                               io.fertPump = 0
                           reg.rTimeToOffInject = 0
                                  if io.fertPump == 0 then f_Inject = 0 -- timer finishef_Inject valve closed
                                  end
                                  if flagFertRunning == 1 then flagInjectFin = 1  -- valve 2 finished lock
                                  end
                    print ("V2 if-3 ",io.fertPump)
         end




  -- reset  fert seqence
   if flagFertRunning == 1 and
      flagAgitateFin == 1 and 
      flagInjectFin == 1 then
            flagFertRunning = 0
            flagAgitateFin = 0
            flagInjectFin = 0
   end

 -- timer for count down
  print(reg.t3second)
          if reg.t3second == 0 then
              reg.t3second = 3
         end
  sleep(1000)
 end
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [codereview.se].

Comment: Just compile the script with the -s option, it will be much smaller

Comment: You can reduce script size from 9953 to 6808 bytes by removing all the indentation.  Lua is not Python :-)

Comment: Use `unexpand` and reduce to 7980 bytes while keeping indentation.

Comment: Thanks for answers  Was first time here I will check out Code Review. cheers